# hibernate adds with nolock in sql server query

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

in the code below

```
String sql =
    "select CAST(MONTH(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS data, SUM(t.quantidade) AS soma from ( "+
    "SELECT distinct tc.* "+
         ", tf.quantidade as quantidade "+
    "FROM tb_faturamento_cliente as tc "+
    "INNER JOIN tb_pico_faturamento tf ON tc.id_faturamento_cliente = tf.id_faturamento_cliente "+
    "WHERE tf.quantidade = ( SELECT MAX(tf2.quantidade) "+
                                "FROM tb_pico_faturamento as tf2 "+
                                "WHERE tf2.id_faturamento_cliente = tf.id_faturamento_cliente ) and "+
    "tc.id_cliente=2 and "+
    "tc.ativo=1 "+
    ") t "+
    "where "+
    "(t.data_referencia BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-01') "+
    "GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(4)) ";

Query query = session().createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List data = query.list();
```

I get the following error in line:

```
List data = query.list();
```

This is the error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'.

hibernate makes this with the query:

```
Hibernate: select CAST(MONTH(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS data, SUM(t.quantidade) AS soma from ( SELECT distinct tc.* , tf.quantidade as quantidade FROM  tb_faturamento_cliente as  with (nolock) tc INNER JOIN  tb_pico_faturamento tf  with (nolock) ON tc.id_faturamento_cliente = tf.id_faturamento_cliente WHERE tf.quantidade = ( SELECT MAX(tf2.quantidade) FROM  tb_pico_faturamento as  with (nolock) tf2 WHERE tf2.id_faturamento_cliente = tf.id_faturamento_cliente ) and tc.id_cliente=2 and tc.ativo=1 ) t where (t.data_referencia BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-01') GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(t.data_referencia) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

hibernate adds with nolock.

do you know why?

Comment: Are you specifying a transaction isolation level in your hibernate config?

Comment: I tried all four possibilities in persistence.xml but didn't solve

Comment: Did you try taking it off?  READ UNCOMMITTED is essentially the same as using `with (nolock)`.

Comment: how, for example?

Comment: Comment out the line that sets it

Comment: Quick fix - ALIAS that table with its own name, and the `as` statement will have a value, getting rid of the syntax error.

Comment: @squillman i didn't find that in project

Comment: @LaughingVergil what about in case of my select max?

Comment: My comment wasn't as good as I thought it was.  It appears that the parser doesn't like the optional `as` keyword in this case. The two instances using `as <alias>` broke, whereas the one case where `as` was not used worked. Try removing it, and see if it works.